# How to convert numbers into multiple lines of digits

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve the [code eval](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/163/) challenge of converting a set of integers into a string of big digits.  I am having a tough time parsing through the digits and print each row separately.

```
digits = {

"0" => 
"-**--
*--*-
*--*-
*--*-
-**--
-----",

"1" => 
"--*--
-**--
--*--
--*--
-***-
-----",

"2" =>
"***--
---*-
-**--
*----
****-
-----"
}


x = 12
x = x.to_s.split('')

digits[char].each_line.with_index do |line, index|
        print line.chomp, "\n"
end
```

I am trying to yield:

```
--*--***--
-**-----*-
--*---**--
--*--*----
-***-****-
----------
```

but I am having trouble.  How do I iterate through and print only one line at a time?  Thanks for your help!  I can so far get it to return and print each digit separately on new lines.

Comment: `x = 12 ... 
x = x.to_s.split('')`   The first line does nothing useful.  In other words, doing this: `x =1, x=2, x=3` is equivalent to writing x=3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the first line of the first digit, then the first line of the second, then the next line of the first digit, then the next line of the second.

```
digits['0'].each_line.with_index do |_, index|
  x.each do |char|
    print digits[char].split("\n")[index]
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

This gives you an outer loop which iterates over lines of a digit (here, '0'). That just gives you a loop to go over each line.

Then you go over each digit of the input, with `x.each`. Then you have to print the "current" line, the number of which is given by `index` from the outer loop. So you get the appropriate digit from `digits`, split on the newline character, index into the appropriate line, and `print` it. Not `puts`, because the next digit goes right next to this one. You print a single newline after printing the `index`th line of all the digits in `x`.

Comment: This makes sense!  I will attempt it and let you know how it works out!

Comment: I like @steenslag's answer better!

Answer (score 0):

```
"0" => 
"-**--
*--*-
*--*-
*--*-
-**--
-----",
```

Is not very practical. The string has 5 line endings, each of which has to be removed every time. An array would be better.

Then create an array of these arrays using `map`. "12" is thus represented as `[["--*--", "-**--", "--*--", "--*--", "-***-", "-----"], ["***--", "---*-", "-**--", "*----", "****-", "-----"]]`. Not quite what you want, but have a look what `transpose`does with that array, and what `join` does with arrays of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
def prnt(h, x)
  puts h.values_at(*x.to_s.chars)
        .map { |c| c.lines.map(&:chomp) }
        .transpose.map { |a| a.join << "\n" }
end
```

```
prnt(digits, 0)
-**--
*--*-
*--*-
*--*-
-**--
-----

prnt(digits, 2)
***--
---*-
-**--
*----
****-
-----

prnt(digits, 10)
--*---**--
-**--*--*-
--*--*--*-
--*--*--*-
-***--**--
----------

prnt(digits, 22)
***--***--
---*----*-
-**---**--
*----*----
****-****-
----------
```

```
prnt(digits, 102)
--*---**--***--
-**--*--*----*-
--*--*--*--**--
--*--*--*-*----
-***--**--****-
---------------

prnt(digits, 202)
***---**--***--
---*-*--*----*-
-**--*--*--**--
*----*--*-*----
****--**--****-
---------------

prnt(digits, 000)
-**--
*--*-
*--*-
*--*-
-**--
-----
```

You might find it easier to just use `String#big_digits`:

```
puts '201'.big_digits
```

### 201