# How to print multiple lines from each sub-array of an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to solve a puzzle that takes in integers and converts them into a stacked string of big digits.  I'm going the route of storing an array of each digit, trying to combine each line of the subarray into creating a final joined string.  So,

```
digits = [
["-**--",
"*--*-",
"*--*-",
"*--*-",
"-**--",
"-----"],

["--*--",
"-**--",
"--*--",
"--*--",
"-***-",
"-----"]
]

digits.each_with_index do |number, index|
    number.each_with_index do |line, row|
        print index, row, line, "\n"
    end
end
```

gives me:

```
00-**--
01*--*-
02*--*-
03*--*-
04-**--
05-----
10--*--
11-**--
12--*--
13--*--
14-***-
15-----
```

How do I make it so that it gives me:

```
00-**----*--
01*--*--**--
02*--*---*--
03*--*---*--
04-**---***-
05----------
```

Comment: Sorry for closing your question temporarily.  It looks very similar to your [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519771/how-to-convert-numbers-into-multiple-lines-of-digits), but it is not an exact duplicate because in this question you are using arrays instead of hashes to store the data.  However, I do ask that you please take the time to review the answers to your previous questions, find an answer that works for you, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
digits.transpose.each_with_index { |a, index| puts "#{index}#{a.join}" }
```

output :

```
0-**----*--
1*--*--**--
2*--*---*--
3*--*---*--
4-**---***-
5----------
```

Exact output :

```
digits.transpose.each_with_index { |a, index| puts "%02d%s" % [index,a.join] }
```

output:

```
00-**----*--
01*--*--**--
02*--*---*--
03*--*---*--
04-**---***-
05----------
```

Comment: Why was it wrong?  It worked just fine, the index is not really necessary, it's just for  sanity check on my part.

Comment: @ppadru1 Nothing wrong. Go ahead! :-) I gave the update lately, as I went to receive my mom's phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
digits[0].size.times do |i|
  printf "%02i%s%s\n", i, digits[0][i], digits[1][i]
end
```

gives

```
00-**----*--
01*--*--**--
02*--*---*--
03*--*---*--
04-**---***-
05----------
```